# How can I connect these two wires?

Tags: batteries, wire, headphones

I wanted to tinker with the microcontroller of the headphones so I cut the solder between these two wires, to stop the power supply.
[image]

Now when I connect the black wire (power ground) lead to the golden wire (audio wire), electricity doesn't seem to pass.

I don't see any wire core like in the black wire inside the golden wire... What is this wire and what is its use ?

What should I do to join them back ?

Comment: To tinker with microcontrollers you should buy a standard development kit. Re-using existing electronic is very difficult and often not possible. It is definitely not suited to gather first experience.

Comment: What you call "the golden wire" looks like audio (headphones or something) while the black one looks more like power (ground, judging by the color.)

Comment: What device is that, and what are the wires you cut?

Comment: Headphones, I updated the question also accordingly

Comment: Your headphones have a microcontroller?  What does it do?

Comment: It is a wireless headset. So there is a pcb on which it is mounted on the other side.

Comment: Which doesn't mean it has a microcontroller - wireless headphones can be built with out a microcontroller.  Even if it's bluetooth, there can be a totally enclosed chip that has power and antenna for input and headphones as output - all the "smarts" hidden away and nothing you can do with it except use it for its designed task.

Comment: Show the spot where you "cut the solder."  It seems to me like you've disconnected a ground wire for power and a ground wire for audio.  They were probably connected to the same place on the PCB - and that spot is where you need to put them back to make the headphones work again.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to solder the wires back where they came from and restore your headphones to normal function.

The two wires were most likely connected together on the PCB - **and** connected to other things on the PCB.

"The golden wire" is a stranded wire insulated with lacquer.

Do the following to get things reconnected:

1. Twist the strands of the "golden wire" back together.
2. Get a large blob of melted solder on the tip of your soldering iron.
3. Poke the end of the stranded wire into the blob of solder.
4. Hold the end of the stranded wire in the melted solder blob for a while - many seconds will be needed until it starts to smoke.
5. Pull the wire out of the solder.  The lacquer should have burned off.  If not, repeat steps 2-4.
6. Tin the wires (stranded and black) and solder them back where they came from.

Your headphones should work again.

---

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to play with a microcontroller then you should find one intended for tinkerers.  The various Arduinos are good for beginners

I would go a step further and suggest you get a book on basic electricity and electronics.  At the very least look up some good (written, with diagrams) tutorials on electricity and electronics.

Starting out with microcontrollers is great, but you won't be able to do much with one if you can't even connect an LED.